# Apace ActiveMQ Artemis 2.32.0 console - Not able to view or browse message

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am not able to view message in Artemis 2.32.0 console using Browse Queue -> Show or Browse option, even after setting the attribute 'management-message-attribute-size-limit' to -1 in the broker xml as mentioned in the documentation.  It displays as '[large message]'.  Has anyone faced this issue ? Any solution please ?

Tried as mentioned in the documentation, but it didn't work.  Reference: https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/

[Edited to add the below]

I checked the same test case and confirmed as below, wherein the message size is more than 1 MB, in both Artemis 2.19.1 and Artemis 2.32.0.

(1) When trying to browse the message in Artemis 2.19.1, it is showing the full soap xml message.

(2) When trying to browse the message in Artemis 2.32.0, it is showing as [large message].

To give you more info,

(1) The client to publish the message, connects to Artemis 2.19.1 (running on Java 8), is org.apache.activemq/activemq-client (uses OpenWire protocol).

(2) The cient to publish the message, connects to Artemis 2.32.0 (running on Java 17), is org.messaginghub/pooled-jms (uses Core protocol).

I am not sure that whether the above difference plays any major role or not ?

Answer (score 0):

The Apache ActiveMQ Artemis web console displays '[large message]' for [large messages](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/large-messages.html), there is no way to the display the body of a [large messaqe](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/large-messages.html) in the web console, for further details see https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.32.0/artemis-core-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/message/impl/CoreMessage.java#L1425

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The same feature was working fine in Artemis 2.19.1.   Is this a change not to show any large message in the latest version ?  I am not able to find anything related this in the Release notes.

Comment: @KarthikSaravanan actually, I get the same result on Artemis 2.19.1, indeed there is the same check, see https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.19.1/artemis-core-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/message/impl/CoreMessage.java#L1410 Can you add a reproducer that works on Artemis 2.19.1 and doesn't work on Artemis 2.32.0 to your question?

Comment: @ Domenico Francesco Bruscino, I have shared the details as much as possible by editing the same question above, as it is too long to put here.